# Closest point pairs in plane implementation issue with SweepLine

Tags: javascript, algorithm, computational-geometry

I'm trying in javascript to implement a solution for the closest point pair problem with a sweep line algorithm.
So far I implemented this

```
function lowerB(pbx, x, y)
{
   for (var p = 0; p < pbx.length; p++)
     if (pbx[p][1] >= x && pbx[p][0] >= y)
       return p;
   return -1;
}

function closestPair(points) {
   // entry point
   let plen = points.length;
   let bestDist = Infinity;

   let pointsBox = [];
   let closest = [];
   let left = 0;
   // we sort points by X
   points.sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0])
   // we push the first point
   pointsBox.push(points[0]);

   for (var i = 1; i < plen; i++)
   {
      // we remove out of bound old points from the pointsBox array
      while (left < i && points[i][1]-points[left][1] > bestDist)
         { left++; pointsBox.splice(points[left], 1); }
  
      // we iterate all points from (X1 - bestDistance to X1) and (Y1 - bestDistance to Y1 + bestDistance)
      let lowerBound = lowerB(pointsBox, points[i][1] - bestDist, points[i][0] - bestDist);
      for (let p = lowerBound; p != -1 && p < pointsBox.length && (points[i][1] + bestDist) >= pointsBox[p][1]; p++)
      { 
         // store bestDistance and closest points
         closest = [points[i], pointsBox[p]];
         bestDist = Math.min(bestDist, Math.sqrt( Math.pow(points[i][1] - pointsBox[p][1], 2) + Math.pow(points[i][0] - pointsBox[p][0], 2)));
      }
      pointsBox.push(points[i]);      
   }
   return closest;
}
```

This seems to work for not a big number of points but I have problems to make it working for random data.
For example with this input (with float numbers):

```
[ [ 1.1819455833862378, 32.24407195815692 ],
[ 2.714088957989979, 42.82018394937117 ],
[ 6.207193653012533, 60.41145194998995 ],
[ 7.492207105975652, 50.6217157701593 ],
[ 10.306099500264738, 68.71396350679889 ],
[ 12.905197415768932, 37.180848834508154 ],
[ 13.34380848909634, 27.75418172488302 ],
[ 16.088206061609306, 46.061989145298035 ],
[ 18.574876021588736, 57.73728098814335 ],
[ 20.697944580169754, 68.00533319326613 ],
[ 21.2008330311723, 39.606348525932546 ],
[ 21.682478199150516, 27.420387703584673 ],
[ 24.788921888520044, 57.963844871715466 ],
[ 25.339883152611637, 44.38503224712771 ],
[ 26.66072141870474, 63.221802424667054 ],
[ 31.39881629585458, 26.2764332318078 ],
[ 31.988520306054408, 33.548012991207145 ],
[ 34.35124648116036, 46.21125562229995 ],
[ 34.89632373696143, 62.80648327849164 ],
[ 36.42097010810934, 53.4422464479575 ],
[ 40.28114923080875, 22.380389471427275 ],
[ 41.99870974032759, 51.23046040123596 ],
[ 42.10838752041404, 42.13746348274942 ],
[ 43.43135141209327, 34.717701928068394 ],
[ 43.936003357885696, 43.80186199626138 ],
[ 46.266301604221994, 61.774514760737965 ] ]

Expected: [[ 42.10838752041404, 42.13746348274942 ], [ 43.936003357885696, 43.80186199626138 ]]
but I get: [[ 41.99870974032759, 51.23046040123596 ][ 40.28114923080875, 22.380389471427275 ]] as closest points which is wrong.
```

Any clue what's wrong there ?

Comment: Closest point pair is a popular problem. According wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem it can be solved with "Divide and Conquer" approach or "Sweep Line". This is the sweepline approach but can't find where is the issue.

Comment: I added some comments. Don't know if this can help

Comment: It's not pseudocode. It works actually

Comment: Well as described works partially. and I don't understand why that's why I posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like my issue was that I mixed Y with X in the delete check.

```
 while (left < i && points[i][1]-points[left][1] > bestDist)
 { left++; pointsBox.splice(points[left], 1); }

// correct
 while (left < i && points[i][0]-points[left][0] > bestDist)
 {  left++; pointsBox = removeById(pointsBox, points[left]); }
```

Also i had to resort by Y after pushing the point in the pointsBox and make the pointsBox behave like a sortedSet. Not trivial in javascript.

```
 // Sorting:
 pointsBox.push(points[i]);
 pointsBox.sort((a,b) => a[1] - b[1]);
```

**Complete solution:**

```
  let plen = points.length;
 ///////////////
 let bestDist = Infinity;
 let pointsBox = [];
 let closest = [];
 let left = 0;
 points.sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0])
 pointsBox.push(points[0]);

 for (var i = 1; i < plen; i++)
   {
     while (left < i && points[i][0]-points[left][0] > bestDist)
       {  left++; pointsBox = removeById(pointsBox, points[left]); }
  
     let lowerBound = lowerB(pointsBox, points[i][1] - bestDist, points[i][0] - bestDist);
     for (let p = lowerBound; p != -1 && p < pointsBox.length && (points[i][1] + bestDist) >= pointsBox[p][1]; p++)
       { 
         closest = [points[i], pointsBox[p]];
         bestDist = Math.min(bestDist, Math.sqrt( Math.pow(points[i][1] - pointsBox[p][1], 2) + Math.pow(points[i][0] - pointsBox[p][0], 2)));
       }
       pointsBox.push(points[i]);
       pointsBox.sort((a,b) => a[1] - b[1]);
   }
   return closest;

   function removeById(pbx, point)
   {
      for (let i = 0; i < pbx.length; i++)
        if (pbx[i][0] == point[0] && pbx[i][1] == point[1])
          { pbx.splice(i, 1); return pbx; }
      return pbx;
   }

   function lowerB(pbx, x, y)
   {
      for (var p = 0; p < pbx.length; p++)
        if (pbx[p][1] >= x && pbx[p][0] >= y)
          { return p; }
       return -1;
   }
```